# Making objects collide in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection

For several days I've been trying to make collision of objects in JavaScript. I have a homework assignment to make a game, so I told why not make a game about Christmas. So I made some snowballs spawn and a Santa to be moved by the arrow keys, all in one canvas.

So now my question. How can I have this Santa and the balls collide and alert something when this happens? I only know how to do it theoretically but can't manage to write down the code properly.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.focus();
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
    var scorevalue = document.getElementById('number').value;
    //canvas dimensions
    var W = window.outerWidth - 300;
    var H = window.outerHeight - 200;
    canvas.width = W;
    canvas.height = H;
    var rectx = 400;
    var recty = 690;
    var rectwidth = 200;
    var rectheight = 200;
    var speed = 50;
    var change = 0;
    var thumbImg = document.createElement('img');
    thumbImg.src = "http://www.gettyicons.com/download/?id=3633&t=png&s=256";
    var character = document.createElement('img');
    character.src = "http://clipartist.info/SVG/CLIPARTIST.ORG/SANTA/santa_claus-999px.png";
    var mp = 11; //max particles
    var particles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
        particles.push({
            x: Math.random() * W, //x-coordinate
            y: Math.random() * H - 1400, //y-coordinate
            r: 13, //radius
            d: Math.random() * mp //density
        })
    }
    var maxMoney = 10;
    var money = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < maxMoney; i++) {
        money.push({
            x: Math.random() * W, //x-coordinate
            y: Math.random() * H - 1600, //y-coordinate
        })
    }
    //var directions = {
    //    "left": -1,
    //    "right": +1,
    //    "up": -1,
    //    "down": +1
    //};                    
    function getRandomValue(min, max) {
        return (Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0;
    };

    function Img(rectx, recty, width, height, speed) {
        this.x = rectx;
        this.y = recty;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speed = speed;

        this.draw = function (ctx) {
            ctx.drawImage(character, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

        };
        this.moveRight = function () {
            this.x += speed;
        };
        this.moveLeft = function () {
            this.x -= speed;
        };
        this.returnCurrentX = function () {
            return this.x;
        };
        this.returnCurrentY = function () {
            return this.y;
        };
        this.xAfterMoveLeft = function () {                 
            return (this.x - speed);
        }
        this.xAfterMoveRight = function () {
            return (this.x + speed + this.width);
        }
    };



    //snowflake particles

    //Lets draw the flakes
    function draw() {
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
        ctx.beginPath();
        for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
            var p = particles[i];
            ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);;
        }
        //ctx.beginPath();
        for (var i = 0; i < maxMoney; i++) {
            var m = money[i];
            ctx.moveTo(m.x, m.y);
            ctx.drawImage(thumbImg, m.x, m.y, 90, 90);
        }
        //ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        //ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        //}
        ctx.fill();
        update();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    //Function to move the snowflakes
    //angle will be an ongoing incremental flag. Sin and Cos functions will be applied to it to create vertical and horizontal movements of the flakes
    var angle = 0;
    function update() {
        angle += 0.01;
        for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
            //Updating X and Y coordinates
            //We will add 1 to the cos function to prevent negative values which will lead flakes to move upwards       
            var p = particles[i];

            p.y += Math.cos(angle + p.d) + 1 + p.r / 4;
            //Sending flakes back from the top when it exits
            if (p.x > W + 5 || p.x < -5 || p.y > H) {
                if (i % 3 > 0) //66.67% of the flakes
                {
                    particles[i] = { x: Math.random() * W, y: -10, r: p.r, d: p.d };
                }
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < maxMoney; i++) {
            var m = money[i];
            m.y += Math.cos(angle + p.d) + 1 + p.r / 4;
            if (m.x > W + 20 || m.x < -10 || m.y > H) {
                if (i % 3 > 0) //66.67% of the flakes
                {
                    money[i] = { x: Math.random() * W, y: -10 };
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //animation loop
    sq = new Img(rectx, recty, rectwidth, rectheight, speed);

    function doKeyDown(e) {
        sq.draw(ctx);
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            var nextX = sq.xAfterMoveLeft();                    
            if (nextX > 0)
                sq.moveLeft();

            //alert(speed + "," + sq.returnCurrentX() + "," + sq.width + "," + canvas.width);
            //alert(speed + sq.returnCurrentX() + sq.width);
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            var nextX = sq.xAfterMoveRight();
            if (nextX < canvas.width)
            sq.moveRight();

        }
        sq.draw(ctx);
        requestAnimationFrame(doKeyDown);

    }

    requestAnimationFrame(doKeyDown);
    function changeScore() {
        document.getElementById('number').value = change++;
        if (document.getElementById('number').value >= 101000000010100101010101010) {
            alert("You have made it :)");
        }
    }
    setInterval(changeScore, 40);
}
```

My HTML body:

```
<canvas style="border:3px solid black; background:red;" ID="canvas" tabindex="1">
    Canvas tag not supported
</canvas>
<input type="number" id="number" value="0" name="score">
```

And my CSS:

```
body {
    /*You can use any kind of background here.*/
    background: black;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
}
```

If you'd like, you can also [take a look](https://www.dropbox.com/s/womkmod01g1n7t3/Game%20for%20TeamWork.htlm) at the full HTML file, and I've setup [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YWu46/) to look at.

I know I am asking a bit too much, but I believe that someone can help me in their free time.

Comment: Please describe your problem in the question, and include the relevant code. Not many people are inclined to download a file.

Comment: Instead of a link to download the source, a live demo (e.g. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)) is more appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up conditions to change the position of each element, the same way you set up conditions to do things collide with the walls.

To do that there are many approaches, but all of them follows the same pattern: you need to detect the collision and then you need to solve it.

To detect the collision you can create a vector between the elements, and see when the module of this vector goes to 0. To get the module you can use a function like this:

```
function module (vector) {             
   var result = 0;
   for (var i  in vector){
    result += Math.pow(v[i],2);
        }
   return Math.pow(result,0.5);
        };
```

which simply follows the mathematics definition of a module.

Then you need to get the distance between the object, that could be something like this:

```
  var distance = {

x : thing1.x - thing2.x,

y : thing1.y - thing2.y

        };
```

And then the condition would be something like:

```
if ( module(distance) < thing1.length + thing2.length )
```

where thing1 and 2 are supposed to be object with a length.

After that, since you just want to get an alert, to solve the conllision is much simpler.